# Standard External Profiles

Tags: community

I'm a newbie salesforce user. What are Standard External profiles? How can I find which users have these profiles. "Allow Users to Use Standard External Profiles to Self-Register and Log Into Communities and Portals" update will be enforced with Spring 21 and our org is seems to be affected by this "it has one or more active users on standard external profiles." Just about any help would be helpful in this matter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[The release notes for "Allow Users to Use Standard External Profiles to Self-Register and Log Into Communities and Portals" contain a full list of the External Profiles](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_networks_standard_profiles_update.htm). I'm including them here for reference:

**This change applies to all orgs using standard external profiles:**

- AuthenticatedWebsite
- BronzePartner
- CSPLitePortal
- CustomerCommunity
- CustomerCommunityLogin
- CustomerCommunityPlus
- CustomerCommunityPlusLogin
- CustomerPortalManager
- CustomerPortalManagerCustom
- CustomerPortalManagerStandard
- ExternalAppsLogin
- ExternalAppsMember
- ExternalAppsPlusLogin
- ExternalAppsPlusMember
- ExternalIdentityLogin
- GoldPartner
- HighVolumeCustomerPortal
- HighVolumePortal
- IdeasOnlyPortal
- LimitedCustomerPortalMgrCustom
- LimitedCustomerPortalMgrStandard
- OverageAuthenticatedWebsite
- OverageCustomerPortalMgrCustom
- OverageCustomerPortalMgrStandard
- OverageHighVolumeCustomerPortal
- Partner
- PartnerCommunity
- PartnerCommunityLogin
- PlatformPortal
- SilverPartner

Comment: Yes. But any way to find out which the licenses of external users ? salesforce says my org "has one or more active users on standard external profiles."How do I find out which ones

Comment: If you want to see what User Licenses your org is using, go to Setup > Company Settings > Company Information and on the Company Information page there will be a table called User Licenses showing you how many you have available and in use. From there you should be able either query for users with those licenses or find the associated Profiles and search by Profile.